# launchd is trying to invoke uninstalled 'SCFinderPlugin.plugin'

Tags: macos, launchd

At some point, I had tried to install and use 'SCPlugin' on Mac OS 10.6 but found that it wasn't what I needed.

According to the installation doc, it said to remove the .plugin file from these locations:

- `/Library/Contextual Menu Items/SCFinderPlugin.plugin`
- `/Library/Receipts/SCPlugin.pkg`
- `/Applications/SCToolbarButton`
- `/usr/local/bin/svn` (if you installed the optional links)

But months after uninstall, I'm still seeing errors reported my console:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[93]   (org.tigris.scplugin.launch[29882])  Exited with exit code: 1
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[93]   (org.tigris.scplugin.launch)         Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[93]   (org.tigris.scplugin.launch[29883])  posix_spawn("/Library/Contextual Menu Items/SCFinderPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/SCPluginUIDaemon.app/Contents/MacOS/SCPluginUIDaemon", ...): No such file or directory
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[93]   (org.tigris.scplugin.launch[29883])  Exited with exit code: 1
```

I did a system-wide search for scplugin and nothing is reported. How do I ensure that that launchd isn't trying to launch the plugin?

Comment: Just as a comment, I never installed SCPlugin, yet I had this same error message in my Console. So I guess that some app (probably a GUI client like Versions or Cornerstone) installs this launch job by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can temporarily stop *launchd* from trying to start that program by entering the following command in a *Terminal* window:

```
launchctl remove org.tigris.scplugin.launch
```

The effect is only temporary because the control file that defines when and how to launch that program still exists and *launchd* will read it again after your next login. You will need to find and delete that file to make the change permanent.

The filename is usually the *launchd* label<sup>1</sup> with `.plist` added to the end. Since I could not be sure of the name or location<sup>2</sup> of the *launchd* file, I downloaded and examined the installable package for *SCPlugin*. It turns out that its file follows the naming convention. The full pathname is `/Library/LaunchAgents/org.tigris.scplugin.launch.plist`.

You should be able to use *Finder* to delete the file. Open a new *Finder* window and navigate to that directory (or press ⌘⇧G, type/paste `/Library/LaunchAgents/`, and click Go), then delete the file (drag it to the Trash or press ⌘⌫; you may need to type your passwword).

---

<sup>1</sup> The label is an identifier that *launchd* uses. The console messages from *launchd* show the label in question: `org.tigris.scplugin.launch`.

<sup>2</sup>
*launchd* looks for files in several directories:

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`
- `/Library/LaunchAgents/`
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/`
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

The last two are supposed to be “system only” (only for things bundled with and provided by the OS), but I have seen third-party software put items under `/System/Library/`.

Comment: Thank-you! It turned out that there a .launch file remaining in /Library/LaunchAgents/.